# objective-c to c - transferring data

Tags: c++, ios, c, objective-c

Here's my code ----

```
//Cpp/Objective-C Wrapper function
iSketchnoteController * isknController;

extern "C"
{
    void launchiSketchnoteController(SlateTableViewController *viewController)
    {
        try
        {
            if (viewController == nil) {

                isknController = new
                iSketchnoteController([MyManager sharedManager].deviceName);
            } else {
                isknController = new iSketchnoteController(viewController);
            }
        } catch (Error &err)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
    }
```

My desired effect is to have `[MyManager sharedManager]` be my "static app state." Meaning, a management system throughout my entire app I can use for things like setting a device name, disconnecting it, reconnect it, etc...

Also, the above is a .mm file.

Anyway - here's how I have it implemented.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@class SelectSlateTableViewController;
@protocol MySwiftProtocol;

@interface MyManager : NSObject
+ (instancetype)sharedManager;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *deviceName;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and the .m file

```
#import "MyManager.h"

extern void disconnect();
extern void connectToPeripheral(CBPeripheral* peripheral);
extern void connectToPeripheralByName(NSString* name);
extern void launchiSketchnoteController(SelectSlateTableViewController *viewController);
extern void isConnected();

@implementation MyManager

+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];


    return self;
}

@end
```

Essentialy, in the first code box `[MyManager sharedManager].deviceName` is *NOT* accessible.

Comment: Why is it tagged  C++?

Comment: C++ is used in my program and I need to it be able to access the MyManager also -- should I add the code?

Comment: You should always stick to [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by "not accessible"? If you received an error from the compiler, you should list it.  Also just curious, why you declaring your externs to C in the .m file as opposed to including the header to the .mm (where I presume they are forward declared)? Is the .mm you listed above complete? Or is it missing things like include/imports?